# LinkedHashSet implementations of HashTable and LinkedList?

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashset

I came across the below in the JAVA docs related to the `LinkedHashSet`:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.

But If I see the source of `LinkedHashSet` I am not able to find any `implements/extends` related to `HashTable` or `LinkedList`. Then how does it inhibits the features of both these `data structures`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not inherit from those classes, or use them in any way.

But you could write your own linked list class, and it would still be a linked list, even if it had no relationship to `java.util.LinkedList`.  That's how `LinkedHashSet` works: it does not use `java.util.Hashtable`, nor `java.util.LinkedList`, but it has an implementation of the *data structures* nonetheless.

Comment: But it does not have any implementations related to add, remove etc. It uses all these of HashSet. Then how is it having those characteristics of linkedlist and hashtable?

Comment: `HashSet` actually has the "linked" implementation in it, for simplicity of implementation; `LinkedHashSet` just uses special superconstructors to activate that behavior.  (`HashSet` is actually just built on top of a `HashMap`, and `LinkedHashSet` on a `LinkedHashMap`.)

Comment: HashSet is built on top of Hashmap, this can be verified from the code of HashSet constructor. How to verify if LinkedHashset is built on top of LinkedHashMap in the same way through the code?

Comment: @ghostrider Track the superconstructor invoked by LinkedHashSet.

Comment: Thank you @LouisWasserman , this was driving me crazy. no way I could have figured out by myself, without spending a lot of time debugging this. Basically this is the constructor called by LinkedHashSet from HashMap class - 
`HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) { map = new LinkedHashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor); }`
It seems strange why HashSet class knows about LinkedHashMap in the first place and then also initialises it's object.